# How to check temp table exists while Union multiple temp tables?

Tags: sql-server-2005, union, temp-tables

here my query-

```
SELECT final.* into #FinalTemp from
    (   
    select * from #temp1 
        UNION 
    select * from #temp2 
        UNION 
    select * from #temp3 
        UNION 
    select * from #temp4
)final
```

but at a time only one temp table exists so how to check if #temp exists then do union or ignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a union or query on a non-existent object at compile time (compiling to a query plan just before execution).

So there is no way to refer to a non-existent table in the same batch

The pattern you have to use is like this: dynamic SQL is a separate batch

```
IF OBJECT('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ('SELECT * FROM #temp1')
ELSE IF OBJECT('tempdb..#temp3') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ('SELECT * FROM #temp3')
ELSE IF OBJECT('tempdb..#temp3') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ('SELECT * FROM #temp3')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not be better creating `#FinalTemp` as an explicit temp table at the top of your query, and then replace your existing population methods which I assume look like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp1 FROM ... /* Rest of Query */
```

With:

```
INSERT INTO #FinalTemp (Columns...)
SELECT * FROM ... /* Rest of Query */
```

And then you don't have to do this final union step at all. Or, if you do need 4 separate temp tables (perhaps for multi-step operations on each), define each of them at the start of your query, and then they *will* all exist when you perform the union.

Now, given you've said only one will be populated (so the others will be empty), it's probably moot, but I always tend to use `UNION ALL` to combine disjoint tables - unless you're implicitly relying on `UNION`s duplicate removal feature?

---

You can declare Temp Tables using the same syntax as you do for real tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #FinalTemp (
    ColumnA int not null primary key,
    ColumnB varchar(20) not null,
    ColumnC decimal(19,5) null,
)
```

Or, as you've also alluded to, you can use table variables rather than temp tables:

```
declare @FinalTemp table (
    ColumnA int not null primary key,
    ColumnB varchar(20) not null,
    ColumnC decimal(19,5) null,
)
```

The predominant different (so far as I'm concerned) is that table variables follow the same scoping rules as other variables - they're not available inside a called stored procedure, and they're cleaned up between batches.

Comment: but how to declare #FinalTemp ? same way like we declare DECLARE @FinalTemp TABLE(Columns...) ??

Comment: @patel - similar, I've added an example.